# Plot does not take range with OptionValue and PlotRange option

Tags: plotting, function-construction, options, optional-arguments

I am making a function that is to use `Show` to overlay a few plots of a function.  I want the first `Plot` in `Show` to get its bounds from the `First` item in the `PlotRange` option.  However, it keeps saying that it is not in the correct form.  However, as far as I can tell it is in the correct form.

```
foo[f_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
 Flatten@{x, First@OptionValue[PlotRange]}
```

This shows that the expression `Flatten@{x, First@OptionValue[PlotRange]}` does provide the correct form for `Plot`.

```
foo[# &, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, Automatic}]
(*{x, -3, 3}*)
```

Now using this in `Plot` returns an error that it is not of the correct form.

```
foo[f_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
 Plot[f[x],Flatten@{x,First@OptionValue[PlotRange]},opts]

foo[# &, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, Automatic}]

Plot::pllim: Range specification Flatten[{x,First[OptionValue[Plot,{PlotRange->{{<<2>>},Automatic}},PlotRange]]}] is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}. >>
```

Any ideas as to why this is the case. The above functions are just to demonstrate the issue. The actual ones are not as simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an `Evaluate` as `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll`.

```
foo[f_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := 
 Plot[f[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, First@OptionValue[PlotRange]}, opts]

foo[# &, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, Automatic}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to `Apply[]` `Plot[]` to the extracted horizontal plot range, like so:

```
foo[f_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := Block[{x}, 
    Plot[f[x], {x, ##}, opts] & @@ First[OptionValue[PlotRange]]]
```

and then `foo[Identity, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, Automatic}]` gives the expected plot.